# Is there a cubic singular at 9 general points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $M$ be a collection of $9$ general points in projective 2-dimensional space. Can I then choose a cubic $C$ that is singular at every point of $M$?
I just read this in a book about algebraic geometry (in the context of Bezouts theorem) where it just says 'let $C$ be the cubic singular at every point of $M$'. Why can I choose such a cubic? I've seen this a couple times now that we are just allowed to choose a curve through some points. An other example was a conic being chosen through $4$ double points and one more arbitrary point. In either situation I don't see why such a curve does exist.

Comment: @KReiser so in the case of the cubic: The vectorspace of forms of degree $3$ is $10$. So does adding one general point for a curve to pass through reduce the dimension by 1? I don't see how to get any intuition for this

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread the problem. Anyways, there can't be a cubic which is singular at nine points: any line through two such points has intersection multiplicity 4 with the cubic, contradicting Bezout. Can you post a full excerpt so we can see what's going on here?